# How to update a the contents of a list displayed on JSP using Struts2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm using Struts2 to display the contents of a list of objects on a JSP.
The flow of events is as following:

1. **GetDataAction.java** -> fetches values from
   the database, fills in the ArrayList
   named `tableList`. On success, the
   `displayData.jsp` is shown.
2. **displayData.jsp** -> uses the `s:iterate` tag to display the values of objects
   in the `tableList`.
3. The user changes some values in the
   `displayData.jsp` and presses on the
   Update button. On the click of
   Update button, the
   **UpdateDataAction.java** is called.

Now my problem is; How do I use the same tableList in UpdateDataAction.java to get the modified values?
I tried declaring an ArrayList with the same name 'tableList' (along with getters and setters), in UpdateDataAction.java but it throws a NullPointerException.

Please suggest.

Comment: how are you updating the values in `displayData.jsp`? Are you upading more than one row at a time?

Comment: Still i need to see how are you updating the values in that list.Are you using a hidden textbox after every value or using some plugin.Can you show me that part of code?

Comment: @anu: I'm simply showing few test fields for each row item in which the user can input some value.

Comment: Try to put your content into a JSON object and send it to the server side via Ajax to update the content of table.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the way you are updating is not a good idea.Either you should link every row to a seperate edit page or use ajax.There are many plugins available to update table values using ajax,If you need i can provide you the links
Back to your way of doing it,i guess you are doing it as follows

```
<s:form action="UpdateDataActionName">
<s:iterator value="tableList">
<s:textfield name="objectName.propertyName1" value="%(propertyName1)">
<s:textfield name="objectName.propertyName2" value="%(propertyName2)">
<s:textfield name="objectName.propertyName3" value="%(propertyName3)">
</s:iterator>
<s:submit value="Update"/>
</s:form>
```

Now declare a list in your `UpdateDataAction`,of type `<objectNameoftableListType>` i.e. the same object type which the tabeList is representing.The name of the list must be `objectName`.Try to Iteate and check if you are getting the right values as submitted from the jsp.