# Struts2 - how to update a collection in a form

Tags: jsp, struts2

I've been researching this for a while. I've read
[How to update a the contents of a list displayed on JSP using Struts2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855732/how-to-update-a-the-contents-of-a-list-displayed-on-jsp-using-struts2)
and it is very close to what I need, but I'm still not quite able to get my problem resolved.

I have a java.util.Set of objects. The class is 'Event', and the name of the set is 'events'. I want to present a form in a JSP that allows the user to modify attributes of the Event objects, but I want to update more than one at a time. Here is my JSP snippet :

```
<s:form theme="simple">
  <table>
    <s:iterator value="events" var="ev">
    <tr>
      <td> <s:textfield name="?????" value="%{#ev.price}" </td>
      <td> <s:textfield name="?????" value="%{#ev.amount}" </td>
     </tr>
     </s:iterator>
     <tr><td colspan="2">
       <s:submit value="Apply" action="EditEventsAction_save" ></s:submit>
     </td></tr>
  </table>
</s:form>
```

My problem is (I think) what needs to go in the name of the texfield in order to update my Set.

How can I specify that the data in the textfield is supposed to update a member of my Set?

Is this possible?

*UPDATE*

This is my latest (simplified) attempt, based largely on what I read in the [type conversion docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/type-conversion.html#TypeConversion-Indexingacollectionbyapropertyofthatcollection).

The form is populated correctly, but changes entered in the textfield are not captured on submit.

Action class:

```
public class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    private static HashMap<Integer, AssetId> assetMap = new HashMap<Integer, AssetId>();

    public String execute () {
        return SUCCESS;
    }   

    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        AssetId a1 = new AssetId(1, "Asset 1");
        AssetId a2 = new AssetId(2, "Asset 2");
        AssetId a3 = new AssetId(3, "Asset 3");
        assetMap.put(1, a1);
        assetMap.put(2, a2);
        assetMap.put(3, a3);
    }

    public String save () {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    public static HashMap<Integer, AssetId> getAssetMap() {
        return assetMap;
    }

    public static void setAssetMap(HashMap<Integer, AssetId> assetMap) {
        TestAction.assetMap = assetMap;
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

<html>
  <body>      
    <s:form theme="simple">
      <table>
        <s:iterator value="assetMap" var="asset">
          <tr>
            <td><s:textfield name="assetMap[key].clientId"  /></td>
          </tr>
        </s:iterator>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><s:submit value="Apply!" action="TestAction_save" /></td></tr>
      </table>
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

`AssetId` class:

```
public class AssetId implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int assetId;
    private String clientId;
    // And public getters/setters
}
```

`TestAction-conversion.properties`

```
Key_assetMap=java.lang.Integer
Element_assetMap=AssetId
CreateIfNull_assetMap=false
```

Comment: Use a map or a collection so there's a key or index to indicate which object the value refers to.

Comment: I have tried a HashMap as well. It's not clear to me how to use the key in the form to reference the correct object.

Comment: I have a new version (using a HashMap) now that uses a unique variable name for each textfield, and a hidden field that holds the hashmap key. Each of these is accessible in the action class as a String[]. This will work, but it seems clunky. Is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Heavens yes. Use mapName[key] as the form field name. Look at the type conversion docs where it talks about collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues; you should have seen stack traces in your log file.

Most important: you didn't check the rendered HTML. If you had, you'd have seen `key` rendering as-is–unevaluated. My fault (comment was incomplete), although the docs show the OGNL escape.

```
<s:textfield name="assetMap[%{key}].clientId" />
```

Since you're trying to evaluate the `key` of the current object of iteration you must wrap it in the OGNL escape sequence–you *don't* want to evaluate the rest. This renders:

```
<input type="text" name="assetMap[1].clientId" value="foo" id="map_save_assetMap_1__clientId"/>
```

*Always check the rendered HTML.*

Eventually the static map will be an issue. It should be an instance property (or, I suppose, a `ThreadLocal`, but IMO you'd struggle to justify that).

You should *not* need the type conversion file at this point; that's largely a legacy artifact. You should have seen an exception about not being able to find the `AssetId` class, too.

Once those things are taken care of if I log the asset map in my submit method, I see:

```
{1=foo.AssetId@502c06b2, 2=foo.AssetId@7a6bb93c, 3=foo.AssetId@364e50ee}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you not only for the solution but the explanation. Debugging this is still a bit of a challenge.

Comment: @ben_979 It always will be ;) Part of the problem is some of the S2 docs are *still* legacy and should be updated, particularly the type conversion bits--I've put it on my list of things to do. Thanks for bringing it up.